# Two LLDB formater get called instead of one

Tags: python, c++, debugging, simd, lldb

In LLDB script I defined two formatter for two types, `int8x16_t` and `uint8x16_t` types.
In each formatter I do a print, and during LLDB debugging, print `int8x16_t` type variable will see the **two prints from the two formatter functions, instead of one**. Is this an expected formatter behaviour?

### Formatter

```py
def print_int8x16_t(valobj, internal_dict):
    print(">>> print_int8x16_t")
    res = 'print_int8x16_t'
    return res

def print_uint8x16_t(valobj, internal_dict):
    print(">>> print_uint8x16_t")
    res = 'print_uint8x16_t'
    return res
```

```py
def __lldb_init_module(debugger, internal_dict):
    debugger.HandleCommand('type summary add -C no -P int8x16_t -F {:s}.print_int8x16_t'.format(__name__))
    debugger.HandleCommand('type summary add -C no -P uint8x16_t -F {:s}.print_uint8x16_t'.format(__name__))
```

### C++ Code

```cpp
// NEON_2_SSE.h
typedef __m128i int8x16_t;
typedef __m128i uint8x16_t;
```

```cpp
#include "NEON_2_SSEN.h"
int main() {
    uint8_t w8u2[16] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18};
    uint8x16_t vw8u2 = vld1q_u8(w8u2);
    uint8_t buf2[16];

    vst1q_u8(buf2, vw8u2);
    printf("Done2\n");

    int8_t w8u3[16] = {-128, -127, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18};
    int8x16_t vw8u3 = vld1q_s8(w8u3);
    int8_t buf3[16];
    vst1q_s8(buf3, vw8u3);
    printf("Done3\n");
}
```

[image]

Comment: The summary formatting always resolves to a single formatter, so I'm not sure what's going on  in your example.  `type summary info vw8u3` will show which formatter was used for this variable.  That might help you figure out what's going on.  If that doesn't help, please file a bug: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issueshttps://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues with your example & results.

Comment: @JimIngham Thanks for reply. With more inspection, I figured out that this is my environment  (VSCode's CodeLLDB plugin related issue, seems loading script each time). In a command line use of LLDB, the formatter related print is unique, as of my expectation.

Comment: Oh, good!  Thanks for figuring this out.